# RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler, runtimeexception, looper

I've got a code with an ASyncTask and the problem is that when I execute it several times it crashes with this exception: RuntimeException: Only one Looper may be created per thread

But then I've read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781280/869180 and I remembered that I had a similar error in the past and it was related to the UI stuff (a ProgressDialog in my case) created in the ASyncTask.

So I took off all the UI stuff from the ASyncTask and I removed Looper.prepare too, to avoid that RuntimeException, but know I'm getting this:

```
12-21 00:34:17.363: W/System.err(18658): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
12-21 00:34:17.371: W/System.err(18658):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
12-21 00:34:17.371: W/System.err(18658):    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:683)
12-21 00:34:17.371: W/System.err(18658):    at com.konex.Alaves.Parser.<init>(Parser.java:29)
12-21 00:34:17.371: W/System.err(18658):    at com.konex.Alaves.News$LoadNews.doInBackground(News.java:131)
```

Here is the code:

```
private class LoadNews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> 
{
    private List<Noticia> data = new ArrayList<Noticia>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        m_dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {

//          Looper.myLooper();
//          Looper.prepare();
            Parser parser = new Parser(url[0], url[1]);
            data = parser.run();

           } catch (Exception e) { 
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        return null;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            m_dialog.dismiss();

        if(data !=null )                
            showNewContent(data);
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something or I am doing something bad, but I'm not able to find it anywhere.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the stack trace tells you, your problem originates from line 29 of `Parser.java`, in the `Parser` initializers. You will note that this is not the source code you included here, which is for `LoadNews`.

Based on the preceding line of the stack trace, either:

- `Parser` inherits from `Activity`
- `Parser` is trying to instantiate an `Activity`

Neither of those is possible.

Comment: Yes, you were right. It was a silly mistake due to hardcoding, Parser was extending Activity when it shouldm't. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instantiate Parser outside LoadNews class and pass reference to it?